# Error The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Tags: java, google-apps-script

tengo este código funcionando (copio solo una parte)

```
var valores = [[FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_NRO_FACTURA).getValue(),  //Nro Factura
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_FECHA).getValue(),   //Fecha
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_MEDIO_PAGO1).getValue(),   //Medio de pago
                 FACTURA.getRange(CELDA_DTO_RGO_GENERAL).getValue(),   //Dto/Rgo general
            
            //Fila 6
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

            //Fila 7
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 1,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila


            //Fila 8
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 2,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x fila

            //Fila 9
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA).getValue(),  //Código
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 1).getValue(),  //Cantidad
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 2).getValue(),  //Descripción
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 7).getValue(),  //Unitario
             FACTURA.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + 3,PRIMERA_COLUMNA + 8).getValue(),  //Dto/Rgo x 
             ]];

datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,valores.length).setValues(valores);
```

y quisiera remplazarlo con este otro

```
var valores = [factura.getRange(CELDA_NRO_FACTURA).getValue(),  //Nro Factura
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_FECHA).getValue(),   //Fecha
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_MEDIO_PAGO1).getValue(),   //Medio de pago
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_DTO_RGO_GENERAL).getValue(),   //Dto/Rgo general
                 factura.getRange(CELDA_OBSERVACIONES).getValue()]  //Observaciones
  
  Logger.log(valores)

  const COLUMNA_CODIGO = 3
  const COLUMNA_CANTIDAD = 4
  const COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION = 5
  const COLUMNA_UNITARIO = 10
  const COLUMNA_DTO_RGO = 11
  const CANT_FILAS_FACTURA = 10
  var cont = 5
  
  for(fila=0;fila < CANT_FILAS_FACTURA; fila++){
    valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_CODIGO).getValue())  //Código
    valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_CANTIDAD).getValue())  //Cantidad
    valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_DESCRIPCION).getValue())  //Descripción
    valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_UNITARIO).getValue())  //Unitario
    valores.push(factura.getRange(PRIMERA_FILA + fila,COLUMNA_DTO_RGO).getValue())  //Dto/Rgo x fila
  }

  Logger.log(valores)
  datos.getRange(datos.getLastRow()+1,1,1,valores.length).setValues(valores);
```

Mi problema es que soy principiante y no se como asignarle los valores a la variable "valores" en el for.
Creo que se agregan con push, pero cuando lo ejecuto me da el siguiente error:
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.